# pgfplots with percentage on the axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw a graph with percentage in x-axis and categories on y-axis. I cannot make the graph to show `%` sign. Here is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S\&P 500 CEOs Past Experience,
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.5, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]

  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(0.17,Sales)  (0.24,Marketing) (0.31,Finance) (0.42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as you can see, I can make the graph with decimal number and ideally I'd like to have `%` sign. Any suggestion?

Comment: Where do you want to show the `%` sign? After every x tick label? On the bar labels? Also, in your real application, are you only going to show four or five bars? In that case, you might want to get rid of the x axis, since all the needed information is already in the bar labels.

Comment: @Jake: Yeah, I would like to show `%` sign after each label. I mean 17% instead of 0.17, 24% instead of 0.24 etc...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `point meta` to perform the multiplication by 100 and

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
```

to add the percentage sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S\&P 500 CEOs Past Experience,
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.5, 
    point meta={x*100},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal}
    ]
  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(0.17,Sales)  (0.24,Marketing) (0.31,Finance) (0.42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want this formatting for the x tick labels, then you can use

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
```

(no need to explicitly give the labels):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S\&P 500 CEOs Past Experience,
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=0.5, 
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
    point meta={x*100},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(0.17,Sales)  (0.24,Marketing) (0.31,Finance) (0.42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use `xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%}`.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
    axis lines*=left,
    title=Histogram of S \& P 500 CEOs Past Experience,
    xbar,
    width=8cm,
    height=5cm,
    xlabel={},
    symbolic y coords={Sales, Marketing, Finance, Operations},
    ytick=data,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=100, 
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    xtick={20,40,60,80,100},
    xticklabel=
{\pgfmathprintnumber\tick\%}
    ]

  \addplot
[draw=blue,pattern=horizontal lines light blue] 
coordinates
     {(17,Sales)  (24,Marketing) (31,Finance) (42,Operations)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]