# How to format date inputed from file in date format and percentage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, formatting, axis, datetime

I have inputs with tuple (date, percent) in a csv file:
(The date are integers with 44 000 <-> 18 June 2020)

```
date,pct
44755,0.01925374
44756,0.01925374
44757,0.01925374
[...]
44768,0.018989264
44769,0.018989264
```

which I load and plot with the following latex code.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \centering   
        \begin{axis}[
            width = \textwidth,
            height = 0.5\textheight,
            xlabel = {$$},
            xtick = data,
            xticklabel style={ rotate=+45},
             ymin = 0.01, ymax =0.02,       
            ytick distance = 0.01,
                ]
         % Plot data from a file
        \addplot[
            blue,
        ] table [x=date, y=pct, col sep = comma]{data.csv};
        \addlegendentry{Data} 
        \end{axis}
     
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

How can I format the xaxis for dates "dd-mmm-yy" and yaxis as percentage "0.00%"

Comment: Not related: `\centering` at this place does nothing sensible and you should remove it. The `pgfplots` package` already loads the `tikz` package, so there is no need to load it separately. `xlabel = {$$}` will let the above code snippet break, so you might want to place something between the two `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `xticklabel` and `yticklabel` options to put into the labels whatever you wish. First of all, you can remove the scientific notation with `scaled ticks=false`.

For the percentages, you could simply multiply 100 with `\tick` which is the variable that stores the current tick value and output the result of this calulation (with a percent sign added to it) to the label via `yticklabel` (see: [pgfplots with percentage on the axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87415/47927)).

To get a proper date formatting, you could make use of the `calendar` library that comes with Ti*k*Z. With the command `\pgfcalendarjuliantodate` you can calculate a date (more correctly, three values for year, month and day respectively that can be stored in three commands) from a given integer. We can again grab this integer via the `\tick` value (which we need to convert to an integer) and add the magic number of 2415019 to it to sync the value of 44000 with the date of 2020-06-18 (I used `\numexpr` for the calculation because Ti*k*Z would run into a dimention-too-large error, but we only need integer calculation here anyways which can be done by TeX directly).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
date,pct
44755,0.01925374
44756,0.01925374
44757,0.01925374
44768,0.018989264
44769,0.018989264
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            height=0.5\textheight,
            xlabel={$x$},
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel style={
                rotate=45,
                anchor=north east
            },
            xticklabel={%
                \pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}%
                \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\numexpr\pgfmathresult+2415019\relax}%
                    {\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}%
                \myday-\pgfcalendarmonthshortname{\mymonth}-\myyear%
            },
            ymin=0.01, ymax=0.02,       
            ytick distance=0.01,
            yticklabel={%
                \pgfmathparse{\tick*100}%
                \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=2}%
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%%
            },
            scaled ticks=false,
        ]
        % Plot data from a file
        \addplot[
            blue,
        ] table [x=date, y=pct, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \addlegendentry{Data} 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you, what is the use of \pgfplotsset{compat=newest} ?

Comment: @stackoverflower Over time, PGFPlots developed its syntax. In order to preserve backwards compatibility, the key `compat`  was introduced. Per default, PGFPlots will choose a most compatible setup that, however, does not fully support the newest syntax. Hence it is always advisable to set this key, for example to `newest`, to get all the current features provided by the package. See section 2.2.2 in the current [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).